# How to manage sampling and command times in a model predictive control application using GEKKO

Tags: python-3.x, gekko

I am using GEKKO for Model Predictive Control (MPC) of a quadcopter (simulated) including a Moving Horizon Estimator (MHE) that calculates mass of the quadcopter and drag force. The command function to the quadcopter requires me to specify a time period (i.e. maintain angles r,p and throttle z during x seconds ). 
The discretization in my estimator is specified as follows:

```
m = GEKKO()
m.time = (0,5,2)
```

The simulation function looks like this:

```
for i in range(cycles):

  #Simulation measurements
  #Request measurements
  #MV inputs

  T.MEAS = throttle_i[i]
  roll.MEAS = roll_i[i]
  pitch.MEAS = pitch_i[I]

  #simulate one step
  quad.move(roll_i[i],pitch_i[i],throttle_i[i],dt).join()
```

where `dt` is the time length of the specified commands. (i.e. maintain roll, pitch and throttle for `dt` seconds ).

How do I make sure that discretization in my simulation matches MHE discretization? Also, how can I find a good balance between sampling rate and commanding rate? I am afraid that commanding too often will make unnecessary minor adjustments to the process, but not sampling often enough will make the estimation less accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always want to use the same sampling time between the [Moving Horizon Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_horizon_estimation) and the simulator. I recommend that you use `numpy.linspace` or else `numpy.arange` to define your time horizon for the estimator.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,5,11)
print(m.time)
m.time = np.arange(0,5.01,0.5)
print(m.time)
```

This gives a horizon 11 time points with a time step of 0.5:

```
[0.  0.5 1.  1.5 2.  2.5 3.  3.5 4.  4.5 5. ]
```

If your simulator takes a measurement with a different sampling interval then you can adjust the 0.5 in `numpy.arange`.

Here is [additional example code for MHE](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#moving-horizon-estimation). If you are using a physical system instead of a simulator then the sample time for the MHE needs to be the frequency that you are updating your measurements and solving the MHE. Here is the [source code for the figure below](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabH) that is sampling temperature data from an Arduino device.

[image: Moving Horizon Estimation]

In this case, the temperature is measured every second and the MHE is re-solved. The total time horizon is 120 sec with 3 second intervals or `np.linspace(0,120,41)` to give `m.time=[0,3,...,117,120]`.

For your second question about finding a good balance between sampling rate and commanding rate, the sampling rate is often limited by how fast the MHE can solve. If you need something faster then a Kalman filter or alternative approach could be used. Generally, a faster commanding rate for a controller is better because you are able to respond to disturbances more quickly. If you are worried about moving the parameter values too frequently, then you could use [DCOST (penalize movement) or DMAX (hard constraint on movement)](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorTuning) in your objective.